# Python Pandas, Selecting Column with „loc“ statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I´ve got the following problem:

If i select some index of my Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=CoordArray[0:,1:],index=CoordArray[:,0],columns=["x","y","z"])
```

like this:

```
print(df.loc[['1234567','7654321'],:])
```

it works pretty well.

but if i have those data in a numpy array, transform this array to a list and do it like this:

```
mynewlist = list(SomeNumpyArray)
print(df.loc[mynewlist])
```

i get the following problem:

```
"None of [[1234567, 7654321]] are in the [index]"
```

I really dont know whats going wrong.

Comment: 1234567 int , '1234567' str

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to replicate your issue. As @Wen commented, your list and numpy array may not have the same types.

Here is an example demonstrating that lists or numpy arrays are acceptable as indexers:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
                  index=['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000'],
                  columns= ['x', 'y', 'z'])

idx = np.array(['2000', '3000'])

df.loc[idx]
#       x  y  z
# 2000  4  5  6
# 3000  7  8  9

lst = list(idx)

df.loc[idx_lst]
#       x  y  z
# 2000  4  5  6
# 3000  7  8  9
```